# Load runner return value from function

Tags: c, loadrunner, load-testing

for whom using HP LoadRunner, Im newly using LoadRunner VUGen, I use "web_submit_data" to send a specific request, I just want to knw how can I ensure that the request sent succsessfully.
I tried the LoadRunner help but there is no details about how to deal with returned values from the function. below are the lines that I'm using in my script.
it give me a syntax errors.

```
            status = web_url("{WebServerURL}",
                "URL=http://{WebServerURL}", 
                "TargetFrame=", 
                "Resource=0", 
               "RecContentType=text/html", 
                "Referer=", 
                "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
                "Mode=HTML", 
                LAST);


            If (status==LR_FAIL)
                {
             lr_end_transaction("PM_01_NavigateToWeightWatchers", LR_FAIL);

             lr_exit(LR_EXIT_MAIN_ITERATION_AND_CONTINUE, LR_AUTO);
                }
            lr_end_transaction("PM_01_NavigateToWeightWatchers",LR_PASS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you need to declare 'status' as an int at the top of the Action() function if you haven't done that already:

int status;

Also, the 'If' in your statement should be lower case:

if (status == LR_FAIL) {
      // code
}

With those changes the code you posted should compile, however it may not be capturing what you think you are capturing. The 'status' that will be returned is telling you whether the function 'web_url()' executed successfully, and that's all. If the page request returns an error page your code would still considered it a success since the function itself executed correctly. It isn't telling you anything about the content of the page you are requesting with it.

If what you really want is to have a look at the response from requesting that page and determining if it worked or not you need to either confirm the presence of a string ( web_reg_find() ) or to correlate values in the page. Use the function '**web_reg_save_param()**' to capture content out of the requested page and write it to the log file, write some error handling around that or to use values later in the script. Look up that function in the help files and study it since learning correlation is they key to getting started with LoadRunner.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are no shortcuts here, you need to attend training from a certified  instructor and you need to be a part of an internship for as much as a year.    This is not a profession you can just be thrown into.

Regarding your question, the topic you seek information on is a topic covered by 30% of the standard web virtual user training class.  This topics is also covered in the product tutorial and it is covered extensively in the product documentation.

This is a path to the answer, not the answer in and of itself.   You are going to have to exercise research skills to get to the answer.

If you are like many individuals you are in this position because your manager has thrown you into this role and handed you the keys to the car (LoadRunner) and asked you to win the Indianapolis 500 (successful performance test).   These cases always result in failure in the performance testing phase, low value to the project, low value to the client.   I would be happy to speak with your project management and your client management directly on how and why this will impact their project on a negative basis, actually increasing the risk in deployment versus reducing it.

A poor performance test is worse than no performance test at all for it unreasonably sets expectations for performance and defects in production.   If you perceive that you are receiving low value from your performance test team because their results never match what is seen in production then you need to start by hiring trained/effective performance testers rather than someone who has a keyword or two on their resume or throwing someone into the role without training.

Comment: Thanks James for your advises,I'm just taking an overview of LR and working on training tests and samples only.
if I get interested in then I'll attend a full training package that me be better in LoadTest Field.